# Which caste was Lord Krishna born into?

Tags: krishna, caste-system, kshatriya, chandravansh, yadavas

What is the caste that Lord Sri Krishna was born into? Was it Kshatriya (warrior) or Yadava (shepherd)? People from the Yadava community claim that Sri Krishna is a Yadava and was born into their caste.

Is Lord Krishna a Kshatriya or a Yadava or is he born into a Kshatriya dynasty named Yadavas?

Comment: He was born a kshatriya - Yadu dynasty is a kshatriya clan. He grew up in a vysya household. Nanda and Yashoda are vysyas. Not shepherds.

Comment: dynasty seems better word than cast..just suggesting if u wish to replace cast with dynasty in Ur question header...

Comment: @YDS Actually, I was interested in caste only because in my state, many people claim that he is not a Kshatriya and he is a shepherd. That's what raised this question. By saying that I don't see Lord Krishna in caste lens or limit him to a caste. He is almighty.

Comment: It appears in the search engines. So? @YDS

Comment: This question is misplaced, is caste = jati or caste = varna ?

Comment: @Akhil I am not complicating things here. I am asking what caste means in present situation. What do you mean by Jati? Is it Race? Nation? Caste?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are verses in "Shreemad Bhagvatam" that points towards  "Lord Shree Krishna's" relation with Pandavas. Although he has been raised in Gokula, Kunti mother of Pandavas was sister of Vasudeva (Father of shree Krishna"). **So we can say that Shree krishna was a kshatriya.**

> तं **मातुलेयं** परिरभ्य निवृतो भीम: स्ययन प्रेमजवाकुलेइंद्रिय:। 
>  
>   यमौ किरीटी च सुह्यत्तमं मुदा प्रवृद्धबाष्पा: परिरेभिरेsच्युतम।।27।।
>
> Tam **Matuleyam** Paribhya Nivritto Bhimah Sasyan Pramjava kule
>   indriya  Yamo kiriti Ch Suhruttmam Muda  Pravrubgdbashpah
>   Paribhirechhutam.
>
> **Meaning** - Then Bheema smiled and hugged  his  "**Maternal** **Cousin**  **Shree krishna"** Nakula ,Sahadeva and Arjuna also hugged Shree Krishna and their eyes filled with tears from the great love
>   towards Shree Krishna.

[**SB 10.71.27**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/71/27)

In that chapter there is also a Verse of  **conversation between "Uddhava" and Shree Krishna**.Where Uddhava is telling Shree krishna to help His "**Paternal Cousins**" pandavas.

> यदुक्तमृषिणा देव साचिव्यं यक्ष्यतस्यत्वया । 
>  कार्यम **पैतृषयव**
>   सेयस्य रक्षा च शरणैषिणाम् ।।2।।
>
> Yadukatamrushina Dev Sachivyam Yakshyatastvaya Karyam
>   **Paitushvaseyasya** Raksha ch Sahranaishinaam
>
> **Meaning** - Bhagvan , as told by "Devarshi Narada" you should help your "**Paternal Cousins**" in their Yagna. Also its a duty of you to
>   help those who surrender to you.

[**SB 10.71.2**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/71/2)

Comment: @SwftPushkar there are some typos in your answers. May be you can fix them. So they are cousins. Paternal or maternal? Why did the theory came into existence that Krishna is a cow shepherd?

Comment: @ShreeCharan -  I think it's because he is raised by  Nanda in Gokula.And from the deep affection of cow shepherd people  towards Shree krishna that theory might have came.

Answer (score 3):

Krishna was born a Kshatriya. The Yadavas are a sub clan of Sona vamsa, which is a Kshatriya sub clan.I think Nanda Baba and Yashoda are of the same yadava clan, as stated in this [Ethnographic Profile](https://books.google.com/books?id=wT-BAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=vasudeva) taken from wikipedia. You can also read this [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-Lord-Krishna-Yadava-or-Kshatriya) article.

Comment: moonstar2001 said that Nanda and yashoda were vysyas. You are saying they might be yadavas. Which is right?

Comment: @SreeCharan I think nanda baba and yashoda are yadavas, because nanda baba is the **cousin** of vasudeva

Comment: Then cattle grazers are Krishna's friends aren't they. How is nanda related to Vasudeva.

Answer (score 2):

Lord Krishna himself says in [Bhagavad Gita 10.37](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=37&etgb=1):

> वृष्णीनां वासुदेवोऽस्मि ...

This is how Swami Gambirananda [translates](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=37&etgb=1) it:

> Of the vrsnis [The clan to which Sri krsna belonged, known otherwise as the Yadavas.] I am Vasudeva;...

---

**Is Lord Krishna a Kshatriya or a Yadava or is he born into a kshatriya dynasty named Yadavas?**

> The Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, the Supersoul in the hearts of all living entities, descended in His original form as a human being in the dynasty or family of Yadu. ~[SB 9.23.20-21](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/23/20-21)

Because Yadu, Madhu and Vṛṣṇi inaugurated this dynasty, so it was known as Yādava, Mādhava and Vṛṣṇi. ~[SB 9.23.29](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/23/29)

Yadu was son of Yayāti as explained in [What is the historical origin of Yadavas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22896/12304)

> Mahārāja Yayāti was a kṣatriya ~[SB 9.18](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/18).

So this is clear that Lord Krishna was born into a kshatriya dynasty named Yadavas (more specifically Vṛṣṇi which was sub clan of Yadavas).

---

[The Mahabharata, Book 5: Udyoga Parva: Section VII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05007.htm) also mention Lord Krishna as the foremost of all Kshatriyas:

> [image: Sanskrit shloka for the foremost of all Kshatriyas]
>
> Dhananjaya the son of Kunti selected **Kesava** who was not to fight on the battle-field, even Narayana himself, the slayer of foes, increate, born among men at his own will, **the foremost of all Kshatriyas** and above all the gods and the Danavas.

Comment: I think the block quotes added in the answer and the note about madhu sudan are redundant. This question is not related to the questions you linked. They ask why Rama/Vishnu is called with a specific name but here, I'm asking what is the caste of the dynasty he was born. Not the dynasty of Krishna. While you are citing other posts as sources, add link to answer not the question.

Comment: Good find, But interestingly the equivalent word for "Kshatriya" is Not found in the original Sanskrit text. So doubtful. From the [Sanskrit equivalent](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs05007.htm): *"19 एवम उक्तस तु कृष्णेन कुन्तीपुत्रॊ धनंजयः
     अयुध्यमानं संग्रामे वरयाम आस केशवम
 20 सहस्राणां सहस्रं तु यॊधानां पराप्य भारत
     कृष्णं चापहृतं जञात्वा संप्राप परमां मुदम"*. It seems that some English lines are added. However, just before those verse, it's found that the Narayani army was made up of "gopAla-s" i.e. cowherds. Which belongs to *Vaishya* division, as stated in my answer.

Comment: Umm..why is the paragraph in bullet points?

Comment: Well, they are not points. It is a paragraph. Bullets should be used for lists or points.

Comment: @iammilind it is mentioned in Sanskrit shloka too...see the updated answer....

Comment: The corresponding link above the verse doesn't show up the verse you have pasted. Can you put the exact link? Even with the above verse, it doesn't necessarily imply that Krishna was Kshatriya, because there is a comparison of deva-danava as well with him. If we assume that the Kshatriya is referring to the virtue or lifestyle of Krishna, then I agree to it. The same is in my answer as well. He did *live* a princely life, which suits a Kshatriya. But the original question asks, *"... born into?"* My interpretation is in my answer.

Comment: @iammilind shloka is from the book, i provided screenshot of it..bcz the english translation of RV/Mahabharat is not found easily along with it's sanskrit verse.. bdw Mahārāja Yayāti was a kṣatriya (mentioned in SB)...Kartvirya Arjun was kṣatriya (Lord Parshuram came to be known as slayer of kṣatriya after killing Kartvirya Arjun, his sons, army)...then from where ur interpretation says that Vrsinis were Vaisyas???

Answer (score 2):

At that time there was no caste (jaati) system. Do not confuse varna system with caste/jaati system. At that time yadava was a clan(kul) though.

Centuries later yadava caste/mostly cow owners - identified themselves with that mahabharata time clan. But reverse is not true, ie we can not identify Krishna with the caste system of centuries later. Because there was no caste system at that time.

Comment: I don't take Jaati as caste. Jati and caste are not same. Its meaning changes with the context There are many definitions of Jaati. Some of them also mean species, nation. Ancient varna system has changed to present day caste system. In present day situation, varna and caste are same. Varna doesn't exist anymore only caste is there. Similarly, Kula also means a caste in these days. It also has meaning of dynasty/clan. Finally, what is your conclusion? What is Varna (caste) Shri Krishna was born? What varna were Yadavas?

Answer (score 0):

Krishna was born in the clan of Maharaj Yadu who was a chandravanshi kshtariya. The name 'Yadav' literally means the offsprings of Yadu (just like 'Manav' means the descendants of vaivshtava manu).
Yadav kshtariyas were later rulers of western India namely Gujarat and parts of Maratha confederacy. Great Vijay Nagar empire of South India was also established by king harihara and bukka of Yadav clan. 
However, Yadavs of northern india especially ganga-yamuna doab region are considered vaishya (shepherd) as they are considered to be related to Nand baba of Gokul who were vaishya.

Answer (score 0):

Vasudevan, Devaki and Rohini were all born as Gopars and Gopis. The Harivamsa and Devi Bhagavata Puranas say the same thing[image][image]

Comment: HI!! Welcome to HSE!! Please visit [FAQ Index for HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) and **specifically** [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)

Comment: What is the second book from which you have taken screenshot? It is interesting that the author has used the story from Devi Bhagavatam and given the reference as Bhagavatam.

Answer (score -1):

**Birth-wise Krishna was a *Vaishya*** (the 3rd division), though he lived a princely life like a *Kshatriya*.
Krishna's caste was **Yadu / YAdava or Vrushni**.

The castes are like family names, which are carried by a person to his son. Probably you meant classes/divisions, which are only 4, based on qualities: i.e. *Brahmana, Kshatriya, Vaishya, Shudra*.

A son/daughter's birth-wise class/division is considered according to their father's lineage. For daughters, it changes after marriage & for sons it may change based on merits & virtues.
However son always carries his father's caste (viz. surname) throughout his life.

Now Krishna's mother Devaki might [or might not] be of *Kshatriya* lineage, however his father Vasudeva was from *Vaishya* (business) category. To be very specific, in such case the division is decided as below:

> The son begotten by a Vaisya upon a Kshatriya woman becomes a **Vandi or Magadha**. The duties assigned to him are eloquent recitations of praise. [[this answer]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22134/1049)

---

Here is how Krishna's class can be considered *Vaishya*:

- Vasudeva was a (real or cousin) brother of Nanda-baba (foster father of Krishna), who was the **chief among the cowherds**. Same thing is true for many Yadu-s. Moreover it was not unusual in many regions to have a *Brahmana* or *Vaishya* or *Shudra* kings as well. Vasudeva's father Sura also could have been a *Vaishya* king.

  > Vasudeva was yadhava king. He was the brother of cowherds tribe chieftain Nanda Baba who was a Surasena.  [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasudeva)
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Dhritarashtra said, 'Hear, O Sanjaya, the celestial feats of **Vasudeva**, feats that Govinda achieved and the like of which no other person hath ever been able to achieve. Whilst being **brought up, O Sanjaya, in the family of the cowherd (Nanda)**, that high-souled one, while yet a boy, made the might of his arms known to the three worlds. [[Dronabhisheka Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07011.htm)
- Another strong reference, is that Kunti was a "real sister" of Vasudeva from same father Sura (or Surasena). Now MAdari refers Kunti as of lower division based on birth.

  > There was amongst the Yadavas a chief named **Sura**. He was the father of Vasudeva. And he **had a daughter called Pritha**, ... gave from friendship this his firstborn daughter unto his childless cousin and friend, the illustrious Kuntibhoja--the son of his paternal aunt [[Sambhava Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01112.htm)
  >
  > ---
  >
  > ... [Madari,] the daughter of the king of the Madras privately addressed Pandu, saying, 'O slayer of foes, I have no complaint even if thou beest unpropitious to me. I have, O sinless one, also no complaint that though **by birth I am superior to Kunti** yet I am inferior to her in station. [[Sambhava Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01125.htm)
- When a *Kshatriya* begets a child with a *Vaishya* woman, the *Kshatriya* order is usually maintained for that child. However the son born under such circumstances, is also referred as *"Karna"*.  Kunti's son from Sun before marriage, was actually named as "RAdheya", was also later known as "Karna". It's quite likely that Karna would have been named/referred so, by some intelligent people (like Bhishma, Vidura), finding similarity of his face with Kunti. This further solidifies that Kunti was from *Vaishya* background, so was her brother Vasudeva, Krishna's father.

  > During that year, O king, was begotten upon her by the illustrious Dhritarashtra a son endued with great intelligence who was afterwards named **Yuvutsu. And because he was begotten by a Kshatriya upon a Vaisya woman, he came to be called Karna.** [[Sambhava Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01116.htm)
- Even the Krishna's Narayani army, consisting mainly of Yadava-s, was referred as the army of cowherds. The profession of cowherd is considered for *Vaishya* division as per BG 18.44.

  > In the left foot, O monarch, was stationed Kritavarma accompanied by the **Narayana troops**, and those invincible warriors, **the gopalas** [[source]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26699/1049)
- Usually a person with non-*Kshatriya* quality used to take the top ministry under the Kshatriya king, e.g. Vidura, who was born to a *Shudra* maid or Yuyutsu, born to a *Vaishya* queen. Similarly Vasudeva was also a prime minister under Kamsa's kingship. Moreover many times Krishna has been referred belonging to cowherd tribe, even though his time with his foster father Nandababa was reasonably less:

  > Duryodhana began to afflict Vasudeva with keen and bitter words, "O son of Kansa's slave, [[Shalya Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09061.htm)
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Bhurisravas said, ... thou hast, unseen by me, cut off my arm ... A man quickly catches the behaviour of those with whom and amongst whom he moves. This is seen in thee, O Partha! Being of royal lineage especially, in Kuru's race, how hast thou fallen off from the duties of a Kshatriya, ... Who else, unless he were a friend of Krishna's, would inflict such a wrong ... **The Vrishnis and the Andhakas are bad *Kshatriyas*, ever engaged in sinful deeds, and are, by nature, addicted to disreputable behaviour** [[Jayadratha-Vadha Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07139.htm)
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Kansa: I will put to death Vasudeva himself, the cowherd Nanda, and my foolish father, Ugrasena, [[Vishnu Purana]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp132.htm)
- An indirect reference: Krishna's one of the name "*Rannchhod*" is due to him [running away from the battlefield](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19313/1049). This is least likely to be a *Kshatriya* like quality as per Gita:

  > [BG 18.43](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=43&etgb=1&choose=1) - The natural duties of the **Kshatriyas** are heroism, boldness, fortitude, capability, and **also not retreating from battle**, generosity and lordliness.
- Traditionally the "cowherds" community belonged to the "Vaishya" (business) class. Refer [BG 18.44](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/44). Now there are few references, which again suggests Krishna's lineage towards that:

  > the king of Chedi (Shishupala) could bear no more, He then replied in rage unto Bhishma in these words...  O Bhishma, in unceasingly praising with devotion, from ignorance alone, **Kesava** so unworthy of praise. How dost thou, from thy wish alone, establish the whole universe in the servitor and **cowherd of Bhoja (Kansa)**?  [[Sisupala-badha Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02043.htm)

---

Of course being a living symbol of supreme reality, the divisions don't bind to the lord Krishna. However, I am just being in the scope of the Qn and discussing Krishna's "birth based division".

Comment: I have found a verse in SB ,where it's said that Shree-Krishna after securing his people ,went  out of Mathura without carrying any weapon.So technically he did not left the battlefield (out of fear ) or so , but only to protect his people , knowing that his people are suffering just because of him & Balarama.Cause Jarasandha's was furious mainly because Shree Krishna killing Kamsa.

Comment: And it's Jaradandha who said this to Krishna (Rann-Chhod) . There is one another instance in SB , where shree-Krishna and Balarama ran away and jumped from mountain.But for specific reason.I will give you that later on.So he did not actually left the battlefield while fighting , but here whole Mathura was the battlefield.

Comment: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/50/57

Comment: Krishna is definitely a Kshatriya, as is Kunti.  Madri is just saying that she is older than Kunti even though she married Pandu later.

Comment: And by the way, Vidura's mother wasn't a Vaishya, she was a fourth-caste person.  That is why Vidura was not a Dvija.  (Vidura not being a Dvija is important because he is used as a test case in Brahma Sutra Bhashyas in the course of showing that only Dvijas are ordinarily eligible for Jnana.)

Comment: @Keshav, your comment on Vidura being son of Shudra is correct (i mixed up Yuyutsu mother earlier). Rest of your comments are mere assumptions. Please write an answer if you have scripture backup.

Comment: @iammilind It's not an assumption at all.  It's overwhelmingly clear that Krishna was a Kshatriya.  Just look at his ancestry.

Comment: And it's ridiculous to say "Now Krishna's mother Devaki might be of Kshatriya lineage, however it's most likely that his father Vasudeva was a Vaishya!" Vasudeva's ancestor Vrishni and Devaki's ancestor Andhaka were both sons of the lunar dynasty king Satvata; see this chapter of the Srimad Bhagavatam: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/24/chapter-view

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, I have added a link to answer of Rannchhod, where Krishna himself admits that all Yadu-s including him, fled Mathura due to fear. However I feel that it's all about which scripture do we trust. :-) There can be other stories too. BTW PAndava-s can be considered Kshatriya due to affiliation with PAndu. But for Krishna's lineage, Vasudeva being brother of cowherd chief Nanda-baba is a decent proof of him being from "Vaishya" lineage. Similarly Kunti the real sister of Vasudeva is also referred by MAdari as from "Vaishya" like lineage.

Comment: @iammilind -ok , nice find.

Comment: Who says that Yadu, Kartvirya Arjun (Sahstrarjun), Madhu and Vrashni were not Kshatriya kings?? They all were Chandravanshi Kshatriya and their descendents too. Lord Parshuram killed Kartvirya Arjuna and then his army and descendents hence known as slayer of Kshatriyas. Arjuna was born in the clan of Puru (younger brother of Yadu) then how come he is Kshatriya?

Comment: @iammilind you himself mentioned that "The Vrishnis and the Andhakas are bad Kshatriyas"...now bad or good but there were Kshatriyas right and not Vaishyas..And from Bhagavad Gita 10.37 it is clear that Lord Krishna was from Vrishnis then, how come you say "Birth-wise Krishna was a Vaishya"???

Comment: @YDS, It was quoted by Bhurishrava during the war. The meaning of Bhurishrava could be that, the Vrishnis were not retaining the fair warring qualities to adhere for being Kshatriya-s. This small reference is just a supportive point to the overall answer, to state that Yadu-s were considered mainly as cowherds rather than Kshatriya-s. To your other question, "how come I say .. Krishna was a Vaishya?" -- For that you may want to read the full answer again. Actually there are multiple points to prove that with scripture back-up. Can't be listed in a comment again.

Comment: @iammilind yes, i hv gone through it several time..and none of the scriptural references is found... it seems ur r seeing work of modern historians...as the question is from Mahabharata time...who are Yadavas in present time doesn't matter..u just cite the sources which tell who were Yadavas at that time...when Yayati, Kartvirya Arjun were kashtriyas how come Vrishnis became Vaishyas..u should cite source for that...

Comment: @YDS, if you have gone through several times, then have you missed many points. In brief: (1) Madri's reference as Kunti being of lower class. (2) Vasudeva as cowherd Nandababa's brother; Kunti was a sister of them. (3) Krishna running away from the battle, even though it doesn't suit a Kshatriya's duties. (4) Krishna being a Yadava and their army was called the army of Gopalas (cowherds). (5) Why was Radheya being referred as Karna ..etc. Also Vrishni was a clan. A clan is big and eventually it's divided in subclans. At best, I am not sure about it; hence my answer doesn't discuss that part.

Comment: @iammilind 1) false claim..may be it's on age or comparison in same Varna 2) read it otherwise,  Sursena was king..after that Ugrasena became king bcz in that janapada next king was decided by majority.. Sursena's one son Vasudev was not king of janapada but was king of jana.. u can't say Vasudev turned into vaisyas... 3) u understood it completely wrong.. 4) again understood wrong... By affection Krishna included cowherds and named on their name.. 5) irrelevant... at last Vrishni is sub clan only...many other sub clans along with Vrishnis makes Yadava clan...

Comment: @iammilind Madri was just saying that Kunti is younger than her.  And Vasudeva was definitely a Kshatriya, and Nandagopa was not his brother.  And Vrishnis and Yadavas are Kshatriyas.