# Did Krishna get defeated in any war during his lifetime?

Tags: krishna, war

During his lifetime, did Lord Krishna get defeated in any war **other than the one with Jarasandha**?

Note that the defeats of Krishna may be *either intentional or unintentional*.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Krishna fled the battle from kalayavana. hence he is affectionately called 'ranachod-rai', but there was hidden reason behind it. There is no 'defeat' for bhagavan ever, because nothing which he doesn't want ever happens.

Comment: Krishna is the supreme lord and no one is greater than him. If he can be defeated it is through his own will. He is defeated only by love and devotion. Just like Mother Yashoda was able to tie him up.

Comment: [wiki/Ekalavya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekalavya) says Ekalavya is known to have defeated krishna in an archery combat.

Comment: @YDS Avoid answering through comments. Post it as answer instead!

Comment: No, because none of His devotees decided to fight against Him. Else He would surely had been defeated.

Answer (score 4):

The assumption that he was defeated in one war itself is wrong. The conclusion of the 18 wars with Jarasandha was that Jarasandha died. So, Sri Krishna being defeated in any war doesn't even come in to question.

This has been explained [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9320/16773) already.

Comment: I mean either intentionally or intentionally... I'm editing question..

Comment: Ok, that won't change the scope of the question. But then, what are you looking for exactly here? We are trying to find proof that he did face defeat? I don't think it exists because it didn't happen. Of course, I am curious to see if others can dig up some material, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO

Krishna never got defeated as explained by Bhishma of who they are.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05049.htm

> It hath been heard by us that the two heroic and mighty car-warriors, Vasudeva and Arjuna, that are now united with each other, are those same ancient gods, the divine Nara and Narayana. **Amongst all on earth they are incapable of being vanquished by the Asuras and the gods headed by Indra himself**. **That Narayana is Krishna**, and that Nara is Falguna. Indeed, they are one Soul born in twain. These two, by their acts, enjoy numerous eternal and inexhaustible regions, and are repeatedly born in those worlds when destructive wars are necessary.

Brahma also said that there is none to rule over Nara and Narayana who are Krishna and Arjuna.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08087.htm

> These two bulls among beings are the Creators of all real and unreal things. These two are Nara and Narayana, the two ancient and best of Rishis. There is none to rule over them. They are rulers over all, perfectly fearless, they are scorchers of all foes. In heaven or among human beings, there is none equal to either of them. The three worlds with the celestial Rishis and the Charanas are behind these two. All the gods and all creatures walk behind them. The entire universe exists in consequence of the power of these two.

Shiva also said that Krishna is unconquerable and invincible to Jayadratha and Arjuna is invincible because Krishna protects him.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08087.htm

> They call Him, **the unconquerable Krishna** with conchshell, discus and mace, and adorned with the emblem of a curl of hair, Divine, clad in silken robes of yellow hue, and the best of those versed in the art of war. Arjuna is protected by Krishna the possessor of these attributes. **That glorious and lotus-eyed Being of infinite power, that slayer of hostile heroes, riding in the same chariot with Pritha's son, protecteth him**! **He is, therefore, invincible**; the very gods cannot resist his power, still less can one with human attributes vanquish the son of Pritha in battle!