Why is Raja Ranchor celebrated?
Ranchor Rai (Krishna after fleeing battle to dakor) celebrated? how does this work alongside our duty to defend dharma, and to show hinduism doesn't teach weakness, or cowardess? why would Bhagavan himself have to run? I get its tshow us something but did the lord of the universe have to run away from men? and does this not teach us to flee and not fight?

Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9262/34973
